# Memory leaks after location.reload

Tags: javascript, html, dom, memory-leaks

I've got some code like below.

```
var domNode = somehowGet();

domNode.someEvent = function(){
    domNode.appendChild(createNodeUsing(window));
};

window.guid = createGuid(); // called at startup
```

After I call location.reload I open DevTools profiler and see some Detached Tree Node and additional Window instance and amount of them is exactly same with amount of reloads.

I.e. if I call location.reload 5 times, there will be 5 additional instances of Window object and all of them have different Guids.

The question is - will the GC free the memory if there are no another references to domNode except those, I showed above ?

Other words I need to know why there are several Window instances

Browser is Chromium some of the latest versions.

Comment: There is more that 10 mb of such code and I'm unable to fix it in a proper way in predicable frame of time. I need to know if such code can cause the memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

domNode.someEvent = function(){ } is a circular reference pattern. domNode got a reference to someEvent which is a attribute, and in this someEvent function, domNode is still referenceable(as closure).

I'm not sure if chrome can recycle the memory, but I think this pattern should be avoided.

See more details here. http://javascript.info/tutorial/memory-leaks#ie-lt-8-dom-js-memory-leak